# Adding HTML <div> inside of element using WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a div with a class inside of a existing element in WordPress/Woocommerce.
I want to make the sale price more pretty :)
Let's start with what I have now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HYZ3.png)

Code:

```
<ins>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>200.00
        </bdi>
    </span>
</ins>
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLnSQ.png)

Code:

```
<ins>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <div class="vh-badge-ears"></div>
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>200.00
        </bdi>
    </span>
</ins>
```

the closest I have come to is adding this code to my functions.php:

```
function bd_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
  if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) :
    $return_string = str_replace( '<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">', '<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><div class="vh-badge-ears"></div>', $price);
    return $return_string;
  else :
    return $price;
  endif;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_sale_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

But by using this code it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGorx.png)

I hope someone here could help me out.

Kind regards!

Comment: `div` is block element and should not be inside `span`. Validate your HTML with [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Can you just use `::before` for this instead?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hey sorry for the nooby question that I'm about to ask, but how would I use ::before?
Like this? :
````.price > ins > .amount {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #28a745;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.price > ins > .amount::before {
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url(./ears.svg);
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: -80%;
}````

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what you are doing, but `::before` will give you one free virtual DOM element that you can do things with, just make sure to give it `content` of some sort, which can just be empty: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/yLqaqbZ

Comment: @ChrisHaas It did seem like a solution but unfortunately the CSS content property doesn't allow HTML markup...
I tried:
.amount > bdi::before {
  content: '<div class="vh-badge-ears"></div>';
}

Comment: And that's where I'm not certain what you are exactly trying to do. If you just want to have something to have a background image, then `::before` is a great choice. The `content: ''` is used to just force the element to be active, you then set normal CSS properties as you see fit. If you need more than one DOM element, then this might not be a good idea.

Comment: Clad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Full credits to @ChrisHaas

Instead of adding a div inside of the element, he recommended using ::before in css.

So the final code that helped me achieve what I wanted is:

```css
.price > ins > .amount {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #28a745;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.price > ins > .amount > bdi::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(./ears.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -80%;
}
```